# SQLite Pattern Matching (APPEARS not CONTAINS)

Tags: sql, sqlite, pattern-matching, sql-like

Normally, pattern matching is done on a “search DB column for query text string” basis - i.e...

```
DB string “A BMW is a fancy car”
Query string “BMW”
SQL: “SELECT car FROM cars WHERE car LIKE ‘%BMW%’;
```

...assuming that I want to find a matching string in a DB.

However, now I want to do it the other way round:

```
DB string “BMW”
Query string “A BMW is a fancy car”
```

Instead of saying “does the string in the db **CONTAIN** my query string”  I want to say “does the string in the db **APPEAR** in my query string”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reverse the condition by concatenating `%` to the db column and then use it for matching the query string like this:

```
SELECT car FROM cars WHERE 'A BMW is a fancy car' like '%' || car || '%';
```